# ¿porque me dice que 'props' no esta definido (no-undef)?

Tags: reactjs

Perdon agrego esta parte del codigo que faltaba, disculpenme.

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

function Timer(props){
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            clock: 0
         };
    }

    return (
        <div className="Timer">
            <p>You have been on this site since: </p><br />
            <span>{this.state.clock}</span><br /><p> seconds.</p>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Timer;
```

Me da error como si 'props' no estuviera definido pero si lo paso como argumento al constructor y tambien al super, no se que esta mal, ayuda y gracias por adelantado al que se tome el tiempo de darme las instrucciones adecuadas.

```
Line 4; 'props' is not defined no-undef
Line 6: 'props' is not defined no-undef`
```

Aqui empieza el codigo React, gracias de nuevo muchachos, no entiendo porque me da este error tan extraño.

```js
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Timer from './Timer';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>Welcom to Timer app built in React.</p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
      <Timer start={Date.now()}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta es la respuesta!! gracias de todas formas :D

```js
import React from 'react';

class Timer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            clock: 0
         };
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div className="Timer">
            <p>You have been on this site since: </p><br />
            <span>{this.state.clock}</span><br /><p> seconds.</p>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

export default Timer;
```

Comment: explica tu codigo esta muy interesante

Comment: Exacto: había que sustituir la línea `function Timer(props){` por `class Timer extends React.Component {`.

Answer (score 0):

Se los tienes que pasar a la función.

```
function App(props) {}
```

Comment: ahora me dice esto  `C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\react\stop-watch\src\Timer.js: super is only allowed in object methods and classes`

Comment: cuando hago lo que tu me dices me dice eso :(

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta es porque en un componente de función no puedes añadir un constructor, ya que no se va a crear una "instancia" de dicho componente como si lo hicieses de un componente de clase, que sí llaman a un constructor cada vez que creas una instancia nueva.